# Is there a way to "cut down" a Java object to a inherited class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

So this is what I noticed in Java:

If I make a class:

```
class IntStorage
{
    public int i;

    public void setInt(int i) { this.i = i; }
    public int getInt() { return i; }
}
```

And inherit it, and store other data:

```
class IntAndStringStorage : IntStorage
{
    public String s;

    public void setString(String s) { this.s = s; }
    public String getString() { return s; }
}
```

And I do this:

```
IntAndStringStorage IandSstorage = new IntAndStringStorage();
IandSstorage.setString("Test");
IntStorage Istorage = (IntStorage)IandSstorage;
IntAndStorageStorage test = (IntAndStorageStorage)Istorage;
System.out.println(test.getString());
```

It's completely valid even though I casted it to a inherited class. Now I assume the info is still inside the object, so could I completely cast it to the inherited class without keeping the old info? I don't want the `String` storage left over in my `int` storage class.

Comment: `class IntAndStringStorage : IntStorage`  Is that Java 8 notation?  It does not compile here.

Comment: hmmm just looking for a little clarification do mean when you cast is the object you store the same object? Also the inheritance syntax looks suspiciously like C#.

Comment: @Nomad101 I mean that the object is still the same object. It's just "masked" as the other type of object.

Comment: That's some actionscript for me ?

Comment: `IntAndStringStorage` **isn't-a** `IntStorage`. Think twice before inheriting.

Comment: By Java naming convention variables should be lowercase first letter. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Casts *do not* change an object in Java (unlike C#, casts in Java cannot be overloaded). Casts thus only change the [compile-time] type the object appears as - it is *always* entirely valid to cast the object back to the original type.

To "cut down" an object would require

1. to create a *new* object (perhaps of a base type) with less information or;
2. have a mutable object that throws out (i.e. assigns null/default values) to various "cut out" fields.

Also, interfaces are generally a nicer way of exposing certain "views" than relying on base types.

Comment: +1 a very good comprehensive answer. I look forward to more of your answers (and your name ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it in Java is to create a new IntStorage based on IntAndDataStorage instance int value.

```
IntStorage intStorage = new IntStorage(intAndSstorage.getInt());
```

assuming you added IntStorage(int) constructor to IntStorage. There will be no String leftovers.

Comment: or adding a copy constructor ;)